# How to rewrite without using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid-api-v3

```
class Mailer extends helper.Mail {
     ...//some methods
   async send() {
     const request = this.sgApi.emptyRequest({
            method: "POST",
            path: '/v3/mail/send',
            body: this.toJSON()
     })

    const response = await this.sgApi.API(request)
    return response }}
```

I looked for the similar question to rewrite it to promise without using async/await but couldn't. Kindly help

Comment: "I looked for other solutions to convert it to promise". Which _other solutions_ have you tried? Convert _what_ to promise?

Comment: Your terminology makes me think you're a bit confused.  `async/await` ONLY do anything useful with promises so if your `await` statement is doing anything useful, then `this.sgApi.API(request)` must already be returning a promise.  So, perhaps what you mean to ask is "How do I rewrite this without async/await"?  Promises are used either way and you're not converting anything to promises.

Comment: @rveerd, I meant that I searched for similar questions on StackOverflow and I tried but it was throwing some error.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually I meant to rewrite it without using async/await

Comment: Then, please edit your question and title to accurately describe what you want using the proper terminology.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Mailer extends helper.Mail {
     ...//some methods
   send() {
     const request = this.sgApi.emptyRequest({
            method: "POST",
            path: '/v3/mail/send',
            body: this.toJSON()
     })

    return this.sgApi.API(request) }}
```

`send()` will return a promise btw.

Comment: Didn't know it was so simple, anyways thanks for the answer